# Elasticsearch: aggregations and one-to-many relationship

Tags: elasticsearch

For a search application I need to display the values for the data fields available. Also these values need to narrowed down by search terms entered by the users.
The values for the data/index fields can be collected via bucket aggregations.
But if there is a one-to-many relationship the problem arrises that the buckets contain values that do not match the search term entered.

So for example with a mapping like this:

```
        PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "product_name": {"type": "text", "index": true},
          "tags": {
            "properties": {
                "tag": {"type": "keyword", "index": true}
                }
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
    PUT _bulk
{"index": {"_index": "my_index", "_type": "product", "_id": "1"}}
{"product_name": "the book you were looking for", "tags": [{"tag": "book"},{"tag": "suspense"}]}
{"index": {"_index": "my_index", "_type": "product", "_id": "2"}}
{"product_name": "combinatorics for the wicked", "tags": [{"tag": "book"},{"tag": "mathematics"}, {"tag": "combinatorics"}]}
{"index": {"_index": "my_index", "_type": "product", "_id": "3"}}
{"product_name": "the story of the lonely bit", "tags": [{"tag": "book"},{"tag": "mathematics"}, {"tag": "suspense"},{"tag": "drama"}]}
{"index": {"_index": "my_index", "_type": "product", "_id": "4"}}
{"product_name": "a vector growing wrong", "tags": [{"tag": "book"},{"tag": "mathematics"},{"tag": "suspense"},{"tag": "drama"}]}
```

An aggregation over all documents in the index:

```
    GET my_index/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "tags" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "tags.tag" }
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

```
 ... "buckets": [
{
  "key": "book",
  "doc_count": 4
},
{
  "key": "mathematics",
  "doc_count": 3
},
{
  "key": "suspense",
  "doc_count": 3
},
{
  "key": "drama",
  "doc_count": 2
},
{
  "key": "combinatorics",
  "doc_count": 1
},
{
  "key": "mystery",
  "doc_count": 1
}
```

]...

This result is fine so long as the values don't need to be narrowed down.
Now suppose a user wants to see only those field values that start with "m".

```
    GET my_index/_search
{
     "query": {
        "wildcard" : { "tags.tag" : { "value" : "m*" } }
    },
  "aggs" : {
        "tags" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "tags.tag" }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this aggregation is:

...    "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "book",
      "doc_count": 3
    },
    {
      "key": "mathematics",
      "doc_count": 3
    },
    {
      "key": "drama",
      "doc_count": 2
    },
    {
      "key": "suspense",
      "doc_count": 2
    },
    {
      "key": "combinatorics",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  ] ...

The buckets are calculated over the documents matching the query. But because there is an one-to-many relationship from product to tags, all the tag values of the query matching products are included in the buckets.

Is there any way to exclude the non matching buckets from the bucket list? So for the example here there should only be one bucket: "mathematics".
Is it necessary to completely denormalize the data for this kind of requirement?

Comment: Could Nested Aggregations help you? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html

Comment: Thanks, core, for the hint. I tried a mapping using nested type, too. But it did not help. Also the aggregation result is correct. What I'm doing is using a aggregation as a means to an end, and aggregations aren't designed for my use case. So unfortunately I will have to filter the aggregated buckets programmatically.